# Android app Privacy Policy issue

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

Namastey!

I have completed my first android app. and i am about to upload it on play store.
But recently i came to know that google play store requires a privacy policy link while uploading application on the store.

I have so many doubts and questions regarding this

1. I don't know how to get or create new a privacy policy for my app?
2. I don't have a company of my own, so how can i write a privacy policy and is it legal to do so?

can anyone tell me how to deal with this situation. I really need some help right now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about privacy policies, not programming. Contact your attorney and inquire about writing a privacy policy.

Comment: @CommonsWare, My apologies if you found this question "off-topic", But since this question got one answer, i'm not able to close or delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a Privacy Policy **if you don't collect** personal information from users through your Android app.

If you do collect personal information (directly or indirectly through a third party such as Google Analytics, AdMob, Mixpanel etc.), then Google Play Store requires you (and the law as well) **to have a Privacy Policy in place.**

Related to your questions:

1. Your Privacy Policy should be adapted based on what kind of personal information you collect from users. Do you collect email address, do you need camera access from users etc.?

   [WordPress.com](https://automattic.com/privacy/) open-sourced their legal agreements (Privacy Policy and Terms of Service) but keep in mind that legal agreements **should be customized based on app, app functionality, and other factors.**
2. This question is better answered by a lawyer but keep in mind that a Privacy Policy is the statement where you need to disclose what, how and why you collect personal information from users.

Depending on your country, it might be helpful to look into the following law acts on privacy of user data:

- CalOPPA in the US
- PIPEDA in Canada
- DPA in the UK
- IT Act 2000 in India
- Privacy Act in Australia